# Construct the URL from JSON feed

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson, flickr

Could anyone please advise me of what am I doing wrong here?

I am trying to construct the image URL but using the flickr.photos.search method
now (I need to display images close to geolocation of the visitor), I had it
working before with groups_pool.gne and the JSON feed was different (simpler)
formatted but now..

The URL is working, I get the array with all the data I need (farm, server,
secret and id) but can't construct the url for the photo.

```
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_\
key=KEY&format=json&privacy_filter=0&media=photos&has_geo=1&accuracy=13&sort=int\
erestingness-desc&content_type=1&per_page=32&extras=geo,owner_name&page=1&radius\
_units=km&radius=1.521739&lat=40.952532&lon=-4.1326349999999366&text=Alcazar&jso\
ncallback=jsonp1320163051486", getJSONimages);

function getJSONimages(data) {
  var htmlString = "";

  $.each(data.photos.photo, function(i,item){
    htmlString += '<img src="http://farm'+ item.farm +'.static.flickr.com/'+
      item.server +'/'+ item.id +'_'+ item.secret +'_m.jpg" />';
  });

  $('#slideshow').html(htmlString);
```

Thank you.

---

I have added the url_m in the extras, in the URL to get the JSON feed and I get the full URL in my feed and that should help as I do not have to concatenate the rest but still doesn't work.

I can't get it to work, and it's extremely frustrating as I know is very simple.
Well, not for me obviously.

This is my function, after I get the url_m in the loop:

```
function getJSONimages(data) {
var htmlString = "";
$.each(data.photos.photo, function(i,item){
// var url = (item.url_m).replace("\", "");
htmlString += '<img src="' + item.url_m + '" />';
});
$('#slideshow').html(htmlString);
}
```

Even if I use the "url" variable or no, same result.

However, I have noticed something.

In the feed using groups_pool.gne, where I am able to pull the photos
successfully, I go to the media.m like that:

```
$.each(data.items, function(i,item){
var biggestSize = (item.media.m).replace("_m.jpg", ".jpg");
htmlString += '<img src="' + biggestSize + '" />';
```

Notice that I have items, then media, then m with it's own value! Is actually
items.[media: {m:PHOTOURL}].

Where as in this other JSON feed using the flickr.photos.search method, I have
the following "object path":
jsonFlickrApi.photos.photo[{url_m:PHOTOURL}]

And try to use this loop:

```
$.each(data.photos.photo, function(i,item){
htmlString += '<img src="' + item.url_m + '" />';
```

I think this is my problem but I don't have any ideas **how to approach** it. It's
obvious there is a different structure between the two feeds:

items.[media: {m:PHOTOURL}]
photos.photo[{url_m:PHOTOURL}]

I am going to research more on jQuery loops. Any ideas?

Comment: If .html() function isn't working you can use .append() instead.
$('#slideshow').append(htmlString); I tried to test your code, but the api key wasn't accepted.

Comment: The URL you are fetching is pretty far from usable as is. There are what appear to be command line linebreak escaping (the slashes at the end of lines). Is that only on stackoverflow? Also worth asking: you've replaced `KEY` with your actual API key right? And the `jsoncallback=blah` -- that's typically added by something like jQuery and identifies a unique request. Is this just an example or are you trying the same callback over and over?

Comment: @Andre Dublin, I have emailed you the key if you would like to try. I could try append after that, but this is frustrating as I was able to construct an URL before, using another JSON feed, just different formatted and it worked. You can all see it here: [link]www.demetriad.co.uk/flickr-test

Comment: @editor, yes, I have replaced the key. I have tried with and without the callback in the URL and there is no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Weirdly these docs don't mention getting the farm. Can you console.log your item in the $.each loop and see what you get? 
http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html

It's clearly the right URL format though assuming you get all of those pieces:
http://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.urls.html

**EDIT**
Can you tell me what this says (in the alert box):

```
$.each(data.photos.photo, function(i,item){
  var url = 'http://farm'+ item.farm +'.static.flickr.com/' + item.server +'/'+ item.id +'_'+ item.secret +'_m.jpg';
  alert(url);
});
```

Comment: I have no idea how to log it. I know is the right format, that's why I am more than sure is the concatenation I have done wrong.. or the the loop.

Comment: Nothing. There's no alert box :/.

Answer (score 0):

A URL is not a JSON object so you cannot parse it.
You're trying get the URL parameters.
Include the following function and use it like this.

```
lat = querySt('lat');
lon = querySt('lon');


function querySt(ji) {

    hu = window.location.search.substring(1);

    gy = hu.split("&");

        for (i=0;i<gy.length;i++) {

            ft = gy[i].split("=");

            if (ft[0] == ji) {

            return ft[1];

        }

    }

}
```

You might want to modify this part

```
hu =window.location.search.substring(1);
```

to

```
hu = yourURLVariable;
```

if you're getting the URL from somewhere else.

Comment: Wait, I am not trying to parse the URL at all but the JSON feed content where I have things like: http://demetriad.co.uk/flickr-test/json.jpg